# Windows deleting PHP which uses fsockopen

Tags: php, windows

I was writing PHP class which uses fsockopen() to connect with IRC server and then I used this class in CLI test file.  Whne I tried to run this, my file and next files which using this class were deleted. I checked everything including Windows Defender but it gave me nothing. Suprisingly when I tired to establish new connect with netcat nothing weird happened. 
What is going on?
My OS is Windows 10

(sorry for my English)